# Saving an Image to Photos Folder In hololens App

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, image-capture, hololens

I'm attempting to capture a photo inside my hololens app. It seems to be working but saving the image to an obscure place that I cant access or view. I want to save it to my pictures library [Described here I think](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders#Windows_Storage_KnownFolders_PicturesLibrary). Or where should i save the image so I can see it in my photos on the hololens.

filePath = C:/Data/Users/JanikJoe/AppData/Local/Packages/HoloToolkit-Unity_pzq3xp76mxafg/LocalState\CapturedImage10.02831_n.jpg

filePath2 = C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/HoloToolkit-UnityVS.Debug_x86.janik/Data\CapturedImage10.02831_n.jpg

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam;
using System.Linq;

public class PhotoCaptureFVTC : MonoBehaviour {

UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam.PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("snap pic taken");
    PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, OnPhotoCaptureCreated);
}

public void OnPhotoCaptureCreated(PhotoCapture captureObject)
{
    photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

    //Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
    Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

    CameraParameters c = new CameraParameters();
    c.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
    c.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
    c.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
    c.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

    captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, false, OnPhotoModeStarted);
}
void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    photoCaptureObject = null;
}

private void OnPhotoModeStarted(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    if (result.success)
    {
        string filename = string.Format(@"CapturedImage{0}_n.jpg", Time.time);
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);
        string filePath2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, filename);

        photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(filePath, PhotoCaptureFileOutputFormat.JPG, OnCapturedPhotoToDisk);
        Debug.LogError("Saved That Image Somewhere" +"FileName: ="+ filename + " FilePath: = " + filePath + " FilePath2: = " + filePath2);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to start photo mode!");
    }
}
void OnCapturedPhotoToDisk(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    if (result.success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Saved Photo to disk!");
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to save Photo to disk");
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be that it is not possible to save directly in the camera roll folder and there is no picture library on the HoloLens.

There is the same question here: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/1458/capturing-photo-in-unity-and-saving-to-disk

I tried the workaround and it works fine. Just move the saved image to the camera roll folder.

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WINRT_10_0
        var cameraRollFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.CameraRoll.Path;            
        File.Move(_filePath, Path.Combine(cameraRollFolder, _filename));
#endif
```